# Symfony, Doctrine order by OneToMany property

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have an issue creating an SQL query.

I have 2 enteties, YouTubeVideo and Views.

A YouTubeVideo can have many views, views are considered "packs" of views, under the property ViewsCount.

Now, lets say i have 1 YouTubeVideo with 3 views.
Views[0].ViewsCount = 200;
Views[1].ViewsCount = 100;
Views[2].ViewsCount = 300;
total would be 600.

How would i construct a query, that queried all youtubevideos and sorted them by the total amount of views they have?

Is it possible to perform this math operation in SQL?

Atm it looks something like this:

```
    $repository = $this->em->getRepository('YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $query->setMaxResults(self::PR_PAGE);
    $query->setFirstResult($firstResult);
    $query = $query->getQuery();
    $youTubeVideos = $query->getResult();

    // foreach ($youTubeVideos as $youTubeVideo ... get all views add them etc.
```

And then i am using usort:

```
    usort($youTubeVideos, array('YT\ScraperBundle\Entity\YouTubeVideo', "compareViews"));
```

But this is not ideal at all, since i am using a limit on the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using DQL instead of annotations.

```
SELECT y FROM YoutubeVideos y JOIN y.views v GROUP BY y.id ORDER BY SUM(v.viewCount)
```